# Is there a way to rename a COM component without actually recompiling the source code?

Tags: windows, com

I have a legacy system that contains an old COM component running under COM+.  We have a need to rename this old component, but we don't have the source code.  Is there any way to rename the component (not the application) without recompiling?

Comment: In theory you could try to simply change the name of the file itself.  I assume you have the source to the legacy system, if you don't, what you want is not possible.

Comment: I've already tried renaming the file.  No luck.  The source I have is not guaranteed to be what is actually in production.  It's a mess.

Comment: If you don't have the production software source then what you want is not possible

Comment: What do you mean by rename? If you want to change the ProgId you might be able to do it with a few registry tweaks.

Comment: By rename I mean that the actual component name under COM+ Applications | MyApplication | Components | MyComponent.Something.  I want to rename MyComponent.Something to MyComponent.SomethingElse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" for the COM class is known as [`ProgID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A programmatic identifier (ProgID) is a registry entry that can be associated with a CLSID. Like the CLSID, the ProgID identifies a class but with less precision because it is not guaranteed to be globally unique.

The identifier's purpose is to provide a mapping to the primary identifier for the class, `CLSID`. Hence, you can manually create another/alternate key with another name, mapping ot the same CLSID, and it is going to do the trick in question.

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\<New-ProgID>\CLSID`
- (default value) = `<Same-CLSID>`

Keep in mind that the key for 32-bit component on 64-bit system is:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\<New-ProgID>\CLSID`

`CLSID` subkey is the primary of your interest, you will supposedly want to duplicate all subkeys and values from your original `ProgID` key (in particular `VersionIndependentProgID` if you have it for your class).

Then, COM+ specific part is ProgID subkey under CLSID, where DCOMCNG (you are referring to in comments as "COM+ Applications | MyApplication | Components") takes names from:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\<Your-CLSID>\ProgID`
- (default value) = `<ProgID>`

Renaming this would have effect on COM+ application. The same keys/values are supposedly used in the application itself (this is true for the first two, and I am not sure about the last COM+ specific one).

Comment: Not quite, the name that COM+ uses comes from `Classes\CLSID\{guid}\ProgID`.  Check {2C3E140B-7A0D-42d1-B2AA-D343500A90CF} as an example.  I have no idea how important it is to match the `Classes\ProgId` key name.

Comment: @HansPassant: I stand corrected here - DCOMCNFG definitely lists from there. There is no other mapping to CLSID there however, so I suppose instantiation goes the usual way anyways. The subkey is hardly used to back-resolve to CLSID since it's already under its CLSID key.

Comment: Note, I didn't find my COM+ info exactly where you said, I actually found it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\<My-CLSID>  I just exported that key and edited all of the references to my old ProgID to my new ProgID.  Called the component with the updated name from my test app and voila!  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: `CLSID` is primary thing, you don't need to change it. `ProgID` that maps to `CLSID` is needed for applications. Then `ProgID` listed under `CLSID` is shown in COM+ Applications UI. So they are all connected. Now when you changed it for UI, just make sure the application that uses this components is still operational.